# python, lxml or etree to get a parent of a node containing some text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

how can i proceed to get the parent node of a node containing a piece of text?

moreover can i use some regexp mecanism as the matched element for searching/filtering, below searching from `re.compile("th[ei]s? .ne")` for example?

say `this one`

```
html = '''<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td><td>4a</td><td>5a</td><td>6a</td></tr>
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td><td>4b</td><td>5b</td><td>6b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td><td>4c</td><td>5c</td><td>6c this one</td></tr>
</table>
<div><div>
<table>
<tr><td>1A</td><td>2A</td><td>3A</td><td>4A</td><td>5A</td><td>6A</td></tr>
<tr><td>1B</td><td>2B</td><td>3B</td><td>4B</td><td>5B</td><td>6B</td></tr>
<tr><td>1C</td><td>2C</td><td>3C</td><td>4C</td><td>5C</td><td>6C</td></tr>
</table>this one
</div></div>
</body>
</html>'''
```

i would like to have an iterator that return:

```
<td>6c this one</td>
```

and then:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr><td>1A</td><td>2A</td><td>3A</td><td>4A</td><td>5A</td><td>6A</td></tr>
<tr><td>1B</td><td>2B</td><td>3B</td><td>4B</td><td>5B</td><td>6B</td></tr>
<tr><td>1C</td><td>2C</td><td>3C</td><td>4C</td><td>5C</td><td>6C</td></tr>
</table>this one
</div>
```

i tried:

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
root.xpath("//text()[contains(., one)]")
```

and

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for e in ET.fromstring(html).getiterator():
    if e.text and e.text.find('one') != -1:
        print "Found string %r, element = %r" % (e.text, e)
```

but the best i can have is the node containing `this one` itself... while i am looking for the parent containing this text. notice that div or table are only for example, i really need to go backward to the parent after finding "this one" rather than filtering xml element containing `this one` because i will not know that this is a div, a table or anything before finding what it contains.

(notice also that it is html and not well formated xml, as i suppose que the second `this one` should have been wrapped in a xml tag)

EDIT:

```
>>> root.xpath("//*[contains(child::*/text(), 'one')]") # why empty parent?
[]
>>> root.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'one')]") # i expected to have a list with two elements td and div
[<Element td at 0x280b600>]
>>> root.xpath("//*[child::*[contains(text(), 'one')]]") # if parent: expected tr and div, if not parent expected table or div, still missing one
[<Element tr at 0x2821f30>]
```

BTW, using the last is ok:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.html
#[... here add html = """...]
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
for i, x in enumerate(root.xpath("//text()[contains(., 'one')]/parent::*")):
    print "%s => \n\t" % i, ET.tostring(x).replace("\n", "\n\t")
```

produce:

```
0 => 
    <td>6c this one</td>
1 => 
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr><td>1A</td><td>2A</td><td>3A</td><td>4A</td><td>5A</td><td>6A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1B</td><td>2B</td><td>3B</td><td>4B</td><td>5B</td><td>6B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1C</td><td>2C</td><td>3C</td><td>4C</td><td>5C</td><td>6C</td></tr>
    </table>this one
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your example output it seems like you want to get the element which contains the specified text `one`. Your description says you want the parent of this node.

Based on this assumption you can get the desired nodes using the following XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'one')]
```

If you really want the parent of this node, you can do

```
//*[child::*[contains(text(), 'one')]]
```

By the way, as you can see I used a predicate to get the node, so I filtered the XML nodes. In my opinion, this is the more logical and readable approach, as it basically say *Give me all the nodes which fulfill the given condition* rather than saying *Give me the output of my condition and from this point on search for the actually desired output*. But you could also do something like the following, which would better match your proposed solution:

```
//text()[contains(., 'one')]/parent::*
```

Comment: yes, i need the element which contains the specified text, i was speaking about the parent because i suppose that the xml parser considers a "not visible" text node containing the text data. Not sure i am right here.
btw i can not get the parent, nor a list of the matching nodes (here 2) see my edit. And any clues on how to have matching on regexp?

Comment: Sorry, my second XPath was not correct, I updated it. The second query you run I would also expect two elements td and div, but I get the same result as you did. If I run this using another XPath/Xquery processor I get the correct and expected result. This looks like a bug in lxml to me. Regarding regex, please take a look at my answer a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934852/lxml-find-div-with-id-post-0-9/16935525#16935525

Comment: @user1340802: Please specify in what way the output of the 2nd XPath is not correct. What output did you receive, and what did you expect to receive?

Comment: @user1340802 It does not return the correct result, but the XPath itself is correct. This is a bug in lxml which does not properly execute this XPath. I tested this in other query processors and it works just fine, so this is not an issue with the XPath, but with lxml. There is nothing we can do about a bug in a specific program. You should contact the developers and submit a bug report.

Comment: @LarsH se the EDIT part of the question, i have already test all the expression & outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> root.xpath("//*[contains(child::*/text(), 'one')]") # why empty parent?
[]
```

This XPath expression selects every element for which the **first** grandchild text node contains 'one'. The first argument to `contains()` is expected to be a string, so XPath takes the **first** node in the result of `child::*/text()` and takes its string value. Since no element has a text node containing "one" as its first grandchild, the answer is an empty nodelist.

```
>>> root.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'one')]")
# i expected to have a list with two elements td and div
[<Element td at 0x280b600>]
```

For the same reason, this XPath expression selects all elements whose **first** text node child contains 'one'. That's why the `<td>` is selected, but the `<div>` isn't: the div's child text node containing 'one' is not its **first** child text node.

```
>>> root.xpath("//*[child::*[contains(text(), 'one')]]")
# if parent: expected tr and div,
# if not parent expected table or div, still missing one
[<Element tr at 0x2821f30>]
```

This faces the same limitation as the previous expression.

Have you tried the last solution that @dirkk proposed,

```
//text()[contains(., 'one')]/parent::*
```

That should avoid your problem with passing multiple nodes as the first argument to `contains()`.